# How to Include spaces in XQuery string-join()

Tags: xquery

```
let $text :=
<a>
  <b>f</b>
  <b>a</b>
  <b> </b>
  <b>l</b>
</a>

return 
  string-join($text/b,"")
```

yields "fal"  rather than "fa l"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string-join` will include spaces, but the constructor may have dropped them according to the effective setting of [boundary space](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-boundary-space-decls).

The result that you are seeing would be correct for a setting of "strip", where you effectively are constructing a node without any boundary whitespace, i.e.:

```
<a><b>f</b><b>a</b><b/><b>l</b></a>
```

You can enforce keeping boundary space by adding this declaration to the query prolog:

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks.  One thing leads to another, so now I have the problem that storing the document in eXist loses the whitespace but only if there are attributes !

Comment: Gunther, how can I do that on Oracle Service Bus transformation? When I try to do so, it show me an erro: "Invalid expression: unexpected token: boundary-space"